# Find the smallest $n$ such that $|e-\sum_{j=0}^n{1\over j!}|<0.001$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the smallest $n$ such that $|e-\sum_{j=0}^n{1\over j!}|<0.001$. I know it has something to do with remainder, or Taylor expansion, but I am week in this material.

What I did is merely: $|1+{1\over 1!}+{1\over 2!}...-\sum_{j=0}^n{1\over j!}|=|{1\over (n+1)!}...|$. What do I conclude? How do I prove this elegantly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the remainder you can find an upper bound for $n$, but there might be a smaller $n$ which is sufficient. The correct remainder is $\frac{e^t}{(n+1)!}$ with $0<t<1$

Comment: $6!=720<1000$ but $7!>1000$.

Comment: How do you find a remainder?
I never understood it. All I know is that this is what is after subtracting the expansion from e, how does it become that?

Answer (score 5):

Estimate the error as $$\begin{align} \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty\frac1{j!}&=\frac1{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}+\ldots\right)\\&<\frac1{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\ldots \right)\\&=\frac1{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n+1}n=\frac1{n!\cdot n}\end{align}$$
On the other hand, the error is clearly $>\frac1{(n+1)!}$, so try to find the smallest $n$ with $n\cdot n!>1000$